# How to sync some data between postgresql and sqlite

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite

I need "sync" some data between postgresql and sqlite. Is not the entire database, some tables. I'm using python.

My scenario:

Main System -> postgresql
Local System -> sqlite

My local system consumes data from main system through of a endpoint (json).

I want to, when is a update in my main system (example: a product change description), my local system update his data.

I thinked something like this:

- Main system has a update
- Main system notify local system
- Local system access and download data from main system
- Local system update his database

Is a better aproach? Somenone has any material about this?

Comment: Or use [Sqlite FDW](https://github.com/pgspider/sqlite_fdw) and directly connect the databases.